# Vertically aligning an image to the bottom of a div tag

Tags: html, css

```
<div class = "column2_SS">
 <img class = "weather_widget" src = "images/weather.png" alt = "Smiley face">
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.column2_SS{
background-color: #f2f7fc;
float: right;
height: 171px;
width: 300px;
background-color: black;  /*#444444*/
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 100px;
border-radius: 7px;
vertical-align: bottom;}

.weather_widget{
vertical-align: bottom;}
```

vertical-align: bottom; doesn't work.
I need to align the weather widget image to the bottom. Any solution?
Find the attached image.
[image]

Edit: 
I have set the background color of column2_SS to black. If the image is bottom aligned the background color should not be black. See the attached image. There is a black row under the image which means that image is not bottom aligned.
[image]

Comment: Could you show us what your current work looks like, with directions as to how you'd like it to look? The image by itself is not really relevant

Comment: @Glubus see the edit

Comment: Have you checked the image's size? Maybe it has a transparent little piece of pixels, or a margin, or stuff like that. Maybe your div inherits bottom-padding

Comment: @Glubus position: absolute; works fine here. Thank You

Comment: No use of vertical-align in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can position an element in relation to its parent using `position: absolute` and playing with the top/bottom/left/right values. `vertical-align` works for inline elements or table cells mostly ([read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)).

```css
.column2_SS {
  background-color: #f2f7fc;
  float: right;
  height: 271px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 100px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  position: relative;
}

.weather_widget {
  position: absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="column2_SS">
  <img class="weather_widget" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU1rX.png" alt="Smiley face">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is one of the classic fixes for this on the web, creating table-look markup...

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="table-cell">
        <img src="path/to/your/img.jpg">
    </div>
</div>

.table {
    display: table;
}

.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Also, absolute positioning will work fine, but I always use it as a last option, because of "jumping" behavior on some devices.